# Cannot create CloudBlobClient in Windows Phone 8.1 Store App with ARM profile

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8.1, arm

When I'm trying to create `CloudBlobClient`, I get this exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.ni.DLL
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The argument 'ParallelOperationThreadCount' is larger than maximum of '64'
Parameter name: ParallelOperationThreadCount
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.CommonUtility.AssertInBounds[T](String paramName, T val, T min, T max)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobRequestOptions.set_ParallelOperationThreadCount(Nullable`1 value)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient..ctor(StorageUri storageUri, StorageCredentials credentials)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
   at App1.MainPage.<Azure>d__4.MoveNext()
```

Here's a code:

```
StorageCredentials sc = new StorageCredentials("name", "token==");
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(sc, true);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient(); //Here's an exception

CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("images");
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(file.Name.ToLower());    //Will be changed to more unique
await blockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(file);
```

This is only when deployed to ARM device, in x86 Emulator everything is working OK.

I also tried this:

```
StorageCredentials sc = new StorageCredentials("name", "token==");
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(sc, true);
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
```

No exceptions, everything is OK.

Here's a packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.5-beta" targetFramework="wpa81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.5-beta" targetFramework="wpa81" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.5-beta" targetFramework="wpa81" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="5.0.3-preview" targetFramework="wpa81" />
</packages>
```

I tried both `preview` and `stable` releases, no luck with ARM devices.